# Adding quick link to user profile (same like [tag:taghere] mechanism)

Tags: feature-request, users-page, magic-links

I think it can be cool to have something like this: [User:Shadow-Wizard]
Parsed as link to the user profile page, much like the tag links that we already have.

What do you say? Comments are welcome. :)

As Grace [mentions in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82317/adding-quick-link-to-user-profile-same-like-tagtaghere-mechanism?noredirect=1#comment201073_82317), more relevant suggestion is using the user ID (e.g. [user:152859]), since display names are not unique. The ID can be easily retrieved from the profile page URL itself:

> [image]

Comment: Would have to be the user id, because the display name can be replicated, actually.

Comment: @Grace good point, edited my question accordingly.

Comment: This suggestion is essentially the same as requests for some sort of `@` syntax that automatically links to the user. (i.e. `@:2598` where 2598 is my user id)

Comment: @jjnguy didn't saw such request yet, sorry.. but `@` is already used to *notify* users.. ?

Comment: it's ok.  No need to apologize.  I was just mentioning it to be thorough.  The `@` is already used to notify.  But it would be nice if it could do both.  I'm sure you would like to know when you were being mentioned in posts.

Comment: Is this discussed elsewhere on Meta? I, too, have *always* missed this feature, and after years of (admittedly light: I'm no power-user) Stack Exchange usage, I'm still surprised every. single. time. I use an @-notification, and it doesn't result in a link (meaning I have to manually copy their profile-link, and edit my comment with it.)

Comment: Relatedly: Do @notifications still work if they're within a link? [@jjnguy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2598/jjnguy), perhaps you could tell me if you get a notification for this?

Comment: [@ELLIOTTCABLE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140656/elliottcable) did you get a ping?

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE not that I'm aware of, and as you can see I believe it doesn't work as a link.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get a ping an hour ago (for the first one); I *did* for the second (just now.) Good to know!