# Link @ to usernames

Tags: feature-request, display-names

Stealing this from OSQA (see here for [an example](http://community.dzonesoftware.com/questions/28152/is-there-an-amazon-image-ami-with-osqa-on-linux.html)) - I suggest that whenever the system identifies a username prefixed by @ (e.g. @ripper234), this text is turned into a link to that user's profile: [@ripper234](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11236/ripper234).

Comment: I also asked something with same goal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82317/adding-quick-link-to-user-profile-same-like-tagtaghere-mechanism :)