# Adding linkage (Not a link) to user when using @ tag

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change of name across all the site (including @reply comments)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71591/change-of-name-across-all-the-site-including-reply-comments)

It would be great if there were some markdown which would automatically link to the user when using the @ tag as sometimes people change their usernames.

**Note** this is independent of creating a physical link as mentioned in these posts:

- [@ comments should link to the named person's profile (like twitter)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/name-comments-should-link-to-the-named-persons-profile-like-twitter)
- [Link @ to usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83906/link-to-usernames)

Comment: In other words, using `[user:164452]` for instead of @Jacob to notify you?

Comment: @Tibbits I mean stackexchange would replace `@Tibbits with [user:152009]` but show `@M. Tibbits` and change it when you changed your username to just `Tibbits`. Notifications would be up to you.

Comment: (Declined) Duplicates: [@<name> comments should link to the named person's profile (like twitter)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/name-comments-should-link-to-the-named-persons-profile-like-twitter), [Link @ to usernames](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83906/link-to-usernames),

Comment: @slhck. This is not a duplicate of the above ^^. His primary desire was that a link be created. My primary desire is that the name be linked in case the *username is changed.*

Comment: But that'd require the name to be linked in the first place, would it? The reason it was declined is that *> Adding another link to comments would make them even noisier than they already are.* (Jeff) -- I know what you're saying, but those two are dependent on each other.

Comment: Indeed, a dupe, as some linking is required even when not visibly/actually linking when rendering. (Like when replacing @slh with `[user:159624]` in the database, which would then show the current username when rendering, with or without an actual link.)

Comment: @slhck. It doesn't need to have a physical link as far as I'm concerned. It could just update the `@username` when a change is made to the username. They are different features and should be treated differently.

Comment: Then the best way would be to phrase it differently, explicitly say you don't want a *publicly linked* username, and elaborate a bit on why it would be useful. Then, flag for a moderator to reopen.

Comment: @Arjan how is that a duplicate? A url link is not the same thing as database link.

Comment: All is handled in the other question (and in many others).

Comment: Very well, a dupe of [Change of name across all the site (including @reply comments)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71591/change-of-name-across-all-the-site-including-reply-comments) then.

Comment: @Arjan. yes it is a duplicate of that post.

Answer (score 3):

From what I gather, many of the occurrences of @-notifications are undesirable - so much so that comments in which it can be fully determined that the notification is redundant, it is removed automatically.

For this reason, I don't think @-notifications are something SE want to advocate with extra features. They are a means to an end as is: providing a point of tracking. As for the argument of user names changing over time, this is a consequence, yes, but comments aren't held in highest regard for the benefit of the content anyway.

Comment: For cases where one can fully determine who's being replied to, there wouldn't be a need to change the (removed) `@mention` when the user changes their name. For all other cases: [changed names](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518) cause pollution too!